# How do I change the color of my RGB LED backlit keyboard?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, keyboard-backlight

I have a custom-built Sager laptop (which is really a great laptop). It has a factory-installed backlit keyboard that can display every color in the Web spectrum, but after installing Ubuntu 20.04, I can't change the color of the backlight. It's stuck at blue.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

With help from "jeremy" at [lambdalabs](https://deeptalk.lambdalabs.com/t/how-to-change-keyboard-backlight-color/849/6), I found a neat solution. I am now able to control the LEDs with no side effects using my `Fn` key and `/` `*` and `-`.

```
git clone https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-keyboard
cd tuxedo-keyboard
make && sudo make dkmsinstall
sudo modprobe tuxedo_keyboard
```

You can even control the keyboard LEDs with the shell:

```
while true; do for c in 0x{FF0000,FFFFFF,0000FF}; do
    echo $c | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/tuxedo_keyboard/color* >/dev/null; sleep 0.2;
done; done
```

Really cool.

EDIT: For anyone getting an error during install such as this one:

```
$ sudo make dkmsinstall              
cp -R . /usr/src/tuxedo-keyboard-3.0.2                                          
dkms install -m tuxedo-keyboard -v 3.0.2                                        
make: dkms: No such file or directory                                           
make: *** [Makefile:42: dkmsinstall] Error 127
```

It may be obvious to some, but you need to install `dkms`:

```
$ sudo apt install dkms
```

...and you're in business.

Comment: this worked perfectly ( and i tried all the "simpler" solutions i could find before...) on custom built laptop with a "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"