# How can I control the keyboardbacklight?

Tags: keyboard, backlight, gigabyte

I bought a Gigabyte G5 MD laptop which came pre-installed with Windows OS. So, I installed Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS as dual OS. Now, The keyboard backlight only keeps the blue light on and I can't find a way to control this. There is only a Windows program on the manufacturer's service website. Help me plz..

Comment: There's no standardization for RGB keyboard lighting. If the feature is locked behind proprietary software, then you need to use the software to get that feature. Many manufacturers that make keyboards like this allow you to store a hardware profile which persists even if you aren't running the software. See if your keyboard has such a feature. If not, then you're probably out of luck. Complain to the manufacturer that you don't appreciate hardware features to be locked behind proprietary Windows-only software

Comment: Your problem is with bios/uefi and support in the kernel. Some people had luck with a 3rd party module,. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298399/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-rgb-led-backlit-keyboard and https://askubuntu.com/questions/184593/reverse-engineer-driver-for-multi-colored-backlit-keyboard-on-clevo-laptops